# Linux Shell if-statements about analyzing strings are equal

Tags: linux, shell

I am a beginner in Shell Programming.I am confused when I execute a program about if statement
Code is as follows

```
echo -n "word 1:"
read word1
echo -n "word 2:"
read word2
if test "$word1"="$word2"
   then echo "Match"
fi
```

I found that regardless of whether I enter the same string,it always prints "Match"

That's what I want to ask,Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add spaces around `=`:

`if test "$word1" = "$word2"`

Without them, you are using `test` on the expression `"$word1"="$word2"` to test if it is empty.

Silly, I know.

From [man test](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test):

> -n STRING
>
> the length of STRING is nonzero
>
> STRING
>
> equivalent to -n STRING

Just to be perfectly clear: First, `$word1` and `$word2` are replaced with the content of the variables, say `hello` and `world` to be original, so you get the string `hello=world`. So indeed, no matter what you will put in these variables, you will get a non-empty string (because of the `=`) and so the test will always pass.